# Mongodb on samba shared directory

Tags: mongodb, azure, docker, samba

I'm trying to setup a mongodb database where the folder it uses for the data is a samba shared directory.

But mongodb refuses to start, I get:

```
[initandlisten] Assertion: 28595:1: Operation not permitted
[initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 28595 1: Operation not permitted, terminating
```

Is there anything I can do ?

Thank you

Comment: What specific version of MongoDB are you using? Can you include more of the log lines preceding this assertion? The [28595 assertion](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v3.2/src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp#L246) appears to be related to opening the WiredTiger configuration file, so I would check that the `mongod` user has full read/write permissions for your `dbPath` and the files/directories within.

Comment: It seems to be an error of `boost:asio`:
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22operation+not+permitted%22&type=Code